# Delete/Clear staticfiles cache in whitenoise

Tags: django, docker, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

I cant seem to find how to refresh the whitenoise static files cache. It has been giving me a problem. Which has persisted even when I removed the specific file causing the problem. The Manifest is still referring to a missing removed staticfile. I would like to clear the cache so that it can be repopulated. I am using a docker-container with django

Answer (score 0):

`python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear --no-post-process`

`--noinput` Do NOT prompt the user for input of any kind

`--clear` Clear the existing files before trying to copy or link the original file

`--no-post-process` Don’t call the post_process() method of the configured STATICFILES_STORAGE storage backend